# If a set is in a σ-algebra, then are the subsets in the σ-algebra as well?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $A \in F$ where $F$ is a σ-algebra. If $B \subseteq A$, is it true that $B \in F$ ?

Intuitively I would say no. A counter example would be

$\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, $A = \{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{1,2\}$ and $F=\{\emptyset,\{1,2,3\},\{4,5\},\{1,2,3,4,5\}\}$ is a σ-algebra.

So am I correct to assume that the claim is generally not correct?

Comment: A minimal counterexample would be $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ with $\Omega$ containing more than one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given a correct counter-example, so yes, it is indeed not correct. Note that a $\sigma$-algebra $F$ on $\Omega$ always contains $\Omega$, by definition. So if $A\in F$ and $B\subseteq A$ were to imply $B\in F$, then applying this to $A=\Omega$ and $B$ an arbitrary subset of $\Omega$ would imply that $F=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is the entire powerset, but that would not be particularly interesting.

Comment: True. Thank you.