# If a family of sets $C$ is a subset of a $σ$-algebra $F$, then are the subsets of $C$ in the $σ$-algebra as well?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Recently I asked this question
[If a set is in a σ-algebra, then are the subsets in the σ-algebra as well?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3943045/if-a-set-is-in-a-%CF%83-algebra-then-are-the-subsets-in-the-%CF%83-algebra-as-well)

involving a set in F rather than a family of sets.

Now the question is

Let $A \subseteq F$ where $F$ is a σ-algebra. If $B \subseteq A$, is it true that $B \subseteq F$ ?

My answer would be that if $E \in B$ then $E \in A$ and therefore$E \in F$ $\forall E$. This means $B \subseteq F$.

So am I correct to assume that the claim is correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You don't need $F$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra. It is always true that if $A \subseteq  F$ and $B \subseteq A$ then $B \subseteq F$. The proof is as you state it (and you have not used that $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. You don't need $F$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra. It is always true that if $A \subseteq  F$ and $B \subseteq A$ then $B \subseteq F$. The proof is as you state it (and you have not used that $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra).

Comment: Yes F in both cases is a set. In the case of $\sigma - algebra$ its elements are just sets by themselves so only the type of elements changes, which doesn't change the property.